# Editing Answers on answers.ros.org

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[originally asked to Tully via email]

What strategies are used for editing answers on answers.ros.org? I've seen a number of edited answers ([like this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/1208/file-conversion-from-urdf-to-xacro)) and I've never understood the reasoning behind it. Is it just to consolidate the best info in the best answer, even if the same information is just a little further down the page?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10256/editing-answers-on-answers.ros.org/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the goal of answers.ros.org is to get people the best answers.  Overall the website is designed to be editable by the active members of the community.  And unlike a mailing list archive it is easy and desirable to update everything, like it was a wiki.  The presentation of the site is a little different from wiki's in that it's structured around the question and answer format, which is good for debugging and troubleshooting, and searching, but not for general documentation.

As a moderator I usually edit questions to make them more accurately phrased. Keep the formatting readable and keep the questions consistent. (For example people tend to ask questions for which the title is completely unreleated.)

And also I update tags regularly, to keep them standardized, and also sometimes new associations are made in the answers.

The most important part as a moderator/member is to build it up as a knowledge base so that if someone else comes to it a month later they get the best answer as quickly as possible.  So occasionally I'll update answers too, generally the answers are more experienced members so they usually need less editing.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-06-16**:
I try to edit answers/questions as the code layout makes it hard to read

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2021-06-13**:
How can we get the option to "Edit" answers or questions?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2021-06-14**:
You can edit your own questions and answers. Editing others posts is reserved for moderators and others who have reached very high karma levels.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2021-06-14**:
Thanks for the answer.